# replace function is removing new line \n character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using `replace` function to remove unwanted characters like this:

```
var test = "one line \n another line";    
test = test.replace(/[^a-z0-9äöåÄÖÅ"\${}()%&#!¡¿?"'><.,;:=\/*+-_ \^]/g, '')
```

Result:

```
"one line  another line";
```

If you have notice the two white-spaces, and it just removed **\n**

What I have noticed is it removes the **\n** but how that can happens if is not specified in the replace regex?

Comment: Just include `\r\n` in that character class. Also, `-` inside the character class should be at the end of the character class

Comment: "*...[How] that can [happen] if is not specified in the replace regex?*" - you're listing characters that should *not* be replaced; the newline character (the `\n` or `\r\n`) is not listed in that group of exceptions therefore it is implicitly specified in the regular expression.

Comment: Ah right, for some reason I thought it was the opposite

Comment: @Gurman I dont understand what you mean with the character -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var test = "one line \n another line";
test = test.replace(/[^a-z0-9äöåÄÖÅ"\${}()%&#!¡¿?"'><.,;:=\/*+-_ \^\r\n]/g, '')
// ________________________________________________________________^^^^
console.log(test)
```